# POST InputStream RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, post, inputstream, resttemplate

I want to POST an InputStream to the Server.
I'm using Spring and therefore RestTemplate to execute my HTTP Requests.

Client

```
    public void postSomething(InputStream inputStream) {
          String url = "localhost:8080/example/id";
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
          restTemplate.postForLocation(url, inputStream, InputStream.class); 
    }
```

Server

```
@PostMapping("/example/{id}")
public void uploadFile(@RequestBody InputStream inputStream, @PathVariable String id) { 
           InputStream inputStream1 = inputStream;
}
```

On Client side I get
`No HttpMessageConverter for [java.io.ByteArrayInputStream]`
And on Server side I get `Cannot construct instance of 'java.io.InputStream' (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information`

Comment: Why not using multipart instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.html) is for `byte[]`, not `InputStream`, just like the name of the class says.

There are no built-in [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) for `InputStream`, but there is a [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html), which can handle e.g. an [`InputStreamResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html).

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter()));
URI location = restTemplate.postForLocation(url, new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the problem. You made my day :)

Answer (score -4):

You cannot transfer streams over HTTP. HTTP is a stateless protocol and it won't support byte transfer. What you can do is

1. Read the whole input stream and output it as a string or any other form
2. Use any UDP form of data transfer (SOAP or sockets)